# ActiveSync/Exchange security policy

Tags: email, security, exchange, active-sync

On my HTC DNA I recently changed from the integrated ActiveSync client to Touchdown.  My corporate IT policy required a PIN to access the device when using the Android client.  Now that I switched to Touchdown, that is set to require a PIN, so I have to enter 2 PINs to read my email.

I removed my account from the Android app, but it seems to have retained the security policies.  Is there a way I can reset the security policies now that the account isn't using the integrated e-mail client?
 - Dave

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to go to `Settings | Security | Device administrators` and remove the appropriate entry.

Comment: That could be correct, except that I don't have a Device Administrators option in the Security menu.  I have Device Administration, but the only option there is Unknown Sources.

Comment: What Android version is running on your device? Is it a stock or a custom ROM you are using? Maybe the "device administrator" settings are at a different place in your system configuration, but it should definitly be there.

Comment: Perhaps it doesn't appear unless there are device administrators defined. (I'm not willing to uncheck the ones I have to find out.)

Comment: I'm running Android v4.1.1.  Device Administrators came up when I installed the app "Where's My Droid", just to test.  But that was the only app that was listed under Device Administrators.  When I removed the app the Device Administrators option disappeared again.