# Lollipop: override security policies (specifically lock screen/Exchange/Office 365)

Tags: lock-screens, security, gmail, exchange, 5.0-lollipop

When I used Android 4.4 (KitKat) on my Nexus 5 I could ignore certain security policies such as a requirement to have a PIN code to unlock the lock screen. After upgrading to Lollipop and the move of Exchange e-mail from the separate E-Mail application to GMail this is no longer possible. Are there any workarounds? E.g., when I used Android 2, there was a hacked version of the E-mail app apk floating around that told the server it enforced the security policies but in fact ignored them.

I have seen a lot of similar questions, e.g.,

[How can I override the Device Administrator security policy so that I can disable the lock screen?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4391/how-can-i-override-the-device-administrator-security-policy-so-that-i-can-disabl)

[ActiveSync/Exchange security policy](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/41086/activesync-exchange-security-policy)

etc but they are all for older versions of Android.

(For everyone that is gonna whine about security policies in my employment agreement, I demanded, and it got approved, a clause that guaranteed me to have root privilegies or equivalent on all my personal IT equipment. My manager accepts this but the IT department is in a different universe. Taking this issue/the IT department to court for breach of contractual agreement is, for obvious reasons, not an option.)

Comment: [Noname](http://android.stackexchange.com/users/82987/noname) asks for clarification (lacking the rep for a comment): *Did you insert the code to bypass exchange security - follow the instructions on their website! Alternatively download the Patched Gmail app [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1749921&page=102).*

Comment: I used Mailwise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the [Mail Wise](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.syntomo.email) app. It bypasses Exchange security, but you won't be able to use the Gmail app.

For details, read this [Mail Wise FAQ](http://mail-wise.com/faq/#bypass).